# How can I use SQL to select duplicate rows of specific fields, allowing a time difference?

Tags: mysql, sql

I record sending emails in a MySQL database, and I want to find duplicate emails that were sent at the same time.

This query works successfully to find emails sent at the *exact* same time:

```sql
SELECT user_id, template, created_at, COUNT(*)
FROM emails
WHERE sender_id = 08347
GROUP BY user_id, template, created_at
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

But if I want to allow a time margin, say `created_at` +/- 5 seconds, I'm not sure how to implement that in the `GROUP BY`.

How can I select duplicate emails allowing a time difference?

**EDIT:**

There could be more than 2 emails sent around the same time, which the query would ideally include, although I realize that could get complicated, for example if there are many identical emails sent a second apart consistently for an hour.

Comment: Why not just round the time to the closest 5 second interval, and group by that? The alternative is trying to chain your records, which might or might not be what you want to do. If email A is sent at 0 seconds, email B is sent at 3 seconds, and email C is sent at 7 seconds, do you want to group A and C together?

Comment: Have you thought of this case: email e1 is sent at time t1, email e2 is sent at time t2 = t1 + 5sec,  email e3 is sent at time t3 = t2 + 5sec. In which group will you count email e2? It could belong to both groups of e1 and e3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example how to achieve what you want.
But it is pretty expensive query. If you have a huge table - this will become very slow. To improve performance I would recommend to create another column `10_sec_period` and update it with some trigger maybe on each insert. And on top of that this new column need to be added to some index.

```
SELECT user_id, 
       template,
       SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(created_at) DIV 60) * 60) AS 10_sec_period, 
       COUNT(*)
FROM emails
WHERE sender_id = 08347
GROUP BY user_id, template, 10_sec_period
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: @user3827510 . . . I'm surprised to accepted this.  It does not do what you want, because two emails sent one second apart could be in different periods.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution would use `exists`:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM emails e
WHERE sender_id = '08347' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM emails e2
              WHERE e2.user_id = e.user_id and e2.template = e.template and
                    e2.sender_id = e.sender_id and
                    e2.created_at > e.created_at - interval 5 second and
                    e2.created_at < e.created_at + interval 5 second and
                    e2.id <> e.id
             )
ORDER BY sender_id, user_id, template, created_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    template, 
    SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(created_at) DIV 5) * 5) AS rounded_time, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM emails
WHERE sender_id = 08347
GROUP BY user_id, template, rounded_time
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the date to unix_time to get the seconds, the divide by 5 and look for the floor to get the group which belong (5 or 0)...Now multiply by 5 to come back the real seconds, in this point only left convert to date again.

Functions:

- **UNIX_TIMESTAMP**: to convert date to unix time
- **FLOOR**: to get the floor from a decimal
- **FROM_UNIXTIME**: to convert unix time to date

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    template, 
    COUNT(1), 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) / 5)*5)
FROM emails 
    GROUP BY 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) / 5)*5) , 
        template, 
        user_id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Comment: `COUNT(1)` ? Is that from the SQL optimizers dark days where `COUNT(1)` was (much) faster then `COUNT(*)`, nowadays this does not provide extra performance or very very very minimal as `COUNT(1)` might be faster to parse/optimize vs `COUNT(*)`